# Compute $\int_Yy\sqrt{z}\sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2} \ d\mathbf{S}$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Compute the surfaceintegral $$\int_Yy\sqrt{z}\sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2} \
>  d\mathbf{S},$$ where the surface $Y$ is given by $z=x^2+y^2, \ y \leq x, \
>  y\leq 0$ and $1\leq x^2+y^2\leq9.$

Looking in my book on the page on surface integrals, they only cover flux integrals using double integrals. And suddenly this question pops up. I hate it when the questions you face are not representet by the book, no example on there is of this kind.

What is this? What am I computing here and how what is an effective system to use in order to solve this kinds of integrals?

EDIT: The area on the xy plane is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any kind of image of the surface? I can't imagine it.

Comment: No I don't :/ But It's not hard to draw actually. In the x-y plane it's a segment of a circular disk with radius from 1 to 3, this area extends upward in a parabolic manner (out of the paper). I'll update the answer so you can see how it looks like on the x-y plane.

Comment: What book are you using? It is hard to imagine one not presenting a surface integral before a surface flux integral, not to mention they are very much related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the
$$(x,\,y)=(r\cos(t),\,r\sin(t))$$
parametrization will be good (I can't imagine it, so we will see if it works).
I'm not so good in the integral names, but I think the $dS$ in your case is not the vector $\vec{n}\mathrm{d}S=\mathrm{d}\vec{S}$:
$$dS=\left|\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial r} \times \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial t}\right| \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}t$$
So the position vector is:
$$\vec{r}=(x,\,y,\,z)=(r\cos(t),\,r\sin(t),\,r^2)$$
The two partial derivate is:
$$\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial r}=(\cos(t),\,\sin(t) ,\,2r)$$
$$\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial t}=(-r\sin(t),\,r\cos(t),\,0)$$
Now we need to calculate their cross's absolute value:
$$\left|\frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial r} \times \frac{\partial \vec{r}}{\partial t}\right|=\left|(-2r^2\cos(t),\,2r^2\sin(t),\,r)\right|=\sqrt{4r^4\cos^2(t)+4r^4\sin^2(t)+r^2}$$
$$=\sqrt{4r^4+r^2}=\sqrt{r^2}\sqrt{1+4r^2}$$
The integrand can be rewritten as:
$$y\sqrt{z}\sqrt{1+4(x^2+y^2)}=r\sin(t)\sqrt{r^2}\sqrt{1+4r^2}$$
Multiplying the $2$ together the integral will become:
$$\iint r\sin(t)r^2(1+4r^2)\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}t$$
I think the variables must be in the following intervals: $r \in [1,3]$ and $t \in [-\frac{3}{4}\pi,0]$
So:
$$\int_{t=-\frac{3}{4}\pi}^{0} \int_{r=1}^{3}  r\sin(t)r^2(1+4r^2) \mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}t$$
$$=\left(\int_{t=-\frac{3}{4}\pi}^{0} \sin(t) \mathrm{d}t\right)\left(\int_{r=1}^{3} r^3(1+4r^2) \mathrm{d}r\right)=-\frac{758}{3}\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)$$

Comment: @Parseval It's still in progress, but I've accidentally sent it.

Comment: Hehe, no worries mate.

Comment: @Parseval Do you think that the parametrization I wrote above is able to reach the whole surface?

Comment: That's simply polar coordinates, it should be ok given the region is "circular". But what about the variable $z$?

Comment: @Parseval $z=x^2+y^2$ was given, so $z=r^2$ with my parametrization.

Comment: But I don't understand what $dS$ is and why you're computing those crosses?

Comment: @Parseval It's a surface integral and $\mathrm{d}S$ is not a vector, right? We've learned that identity for the $\mathrm{d}S-\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v$, when we are using $u$ and $v$ as the parameters.

Comment: Wow, that was correct. Seriosuly I have to learn this.

Comment: That absolute value of the crossproduct, is it something like using the Jacobian when evaluating a double integral with change of variables?

Comment: No, it was correct earlier, your range for $r$ and $t$ were correct and they're easy to see. You messed up now.

Comment: @Parseval Really? The previous ranges were the correct? It's a bit hard to explain that, but the vector inside the absolute value is normal to the surface.

Comment: @Parseval So the correct answer is $-42(2+\sqrt{2})$?

Comment: Yes it was correct earlier with $r\in[1,3]$ and $t\in[-3\pi/4,0].$ Yes I know that, hmm, let me read up a bit on the theory of that. But as for solving the problem I think this cleared up a few things.

Comment: No, correct answer is $-\frac{758\sqrt{2}+1516}{3}.$

Comment: @Parseval Ahh yes, I've missed out an $r^2$!

Comment: @Parseval Sorry, I can't explain it well, I think. But I hope my answer can help a bit.